# PHP: Parsing XML - output with style

Tags: php, xml, php-parser

I have done this little script.

```
<?php 
$url = "http://resurse.fibula.ro/parteneri/xmlhotels.php?location=belek&myid=travelplaza";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($xml->hotel as $hotel)
{
echo "<p>";
echo "<strong>Title:</strong> ".$hotel->description."<br/>";
echo "</p>";

}
```

In the link above I've some images that I want to put under the description of each hotel.
I have tried to get the images like i did with the description, like so:

```
echo .$hotel->images"<br/>";
```

But I get an error

```
" Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\home\2.php on line 9"
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. An example or o resource where to read about it. For dummies I mean.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

line 9 should look like this:

```
echo $hotel->images . "<br/>";
```

Having the `.` between the variable and the `<br/>` string. I encourage you to learn the basic PHP syntax.

Comment: added this linne but now i get this result : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"<br/>"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\home\2.php on line 9

Comment: Inseted the above echo ... but... it gives me no error, but there are no images showing. If you acces the link directly you can see the images url.